# Send limited data from back-end (Laravel) to front-end (Inertia, React)

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I'm very new to Laravel also client side rendering.

The thing with Client Side Rendering is we have to be very careful while sending data to front-end.

I'm not sure how can I do it for nested relations. Also I don't want to do this at the query level instead filtering it afterwards.

Like,

```php
$user = User::with('blogs.comments.user')->find(1);
```

I mean i can do

```php
$user->only('id', 'name', 'blogs');
```

It will work but only on the first user layer not for relations.

Thank you so much for reading.. :)

Comment: I don't have experience with inertia, but as a general rule you create a transformer class and transform your user and related models to an array which you have complete control over. Although it might seem like a lot of work, it pays off when you can reuse it or change what you send to front by just changing one file.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use Laravel resources.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources

From documentation;

```
php artisan make:resource UserResource
```

```
use App\Http\Resources\PostResource;
 
/**
 * Transform the resource into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'posts' => PostResource::collection($this->posts),
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can archived that simply using WhereHas

```
      $user = User::with('blogs.comments.user')
                        ->whereHas('blogs',function($query)
                        {
                            $query->select('id','name')
                                ->whereHas('comments',function($qu)
                                {
                                    $qu->select('id','name')
                                        ->whereHas('user',function($q)
                                        {
                                            $q->select('id','name');
                                        });
                                });
                        })
                        ->find(1);
```

Comment: It works, but I've already mentioned that I don't want to do this on the query level.